# Sharing memory mapped numpy arrays across functions without segmentation faults

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, segmentation-fault, shared-memory

I am trying to share numpy ndarrays with zero memory copies across python processes, but I keep getting segmentation faults. The main problem is that as far as the main thread is inside the function that loaded an array, everything works fine. However, if I pass the array to a subfunction or return it to the parent function, it fails.

To simplify the error, I coded this little sequential example that simply creates a numpy ndarray (generate_integer_array()), maps it into memory (put_np()), loads it from memory (get_np()) and performs a simple sum operation.

```py
from multiprocessing import shared_memory
import numpy as np

NP_SHARED_NAME = "sharednp"
ARRAY_SHAPE = (1000, )
NP_DATA_TYPE = np.int64

def generate_integer_array(size):
    return np.random.randint(-100, 100, size)


def release_shared(name):
    shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=name, create=False)
    shm.close()
    shm.unlink()


def put_np(data: np.ndarray):

    np_data_type = data.dtype
    np_shape = data.shape

    d_size = np.dtype(np_data_type).itemsize * np.prod(np_shape)

    shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=d_size, name=NP_SHARED_NAME)
    # numpy array on shared memory buffer
    dst = np.ndarray(shape=np_shape, dtype=np_data_type, buffer=shm.buf)
    dst[:] = data[:]
    return shm.name

def get_np(name):
    shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=name)
    np_array = np.ndarray(ARRAY_SHAPE, dtype=NP_DATA_TYPE, buffer=shm.buf)
    print(np.sum(np_array))
    return np_array



if __name__ == '__main__':

    data = generate_integer_array(1000)

    sm_name = put_np(data)
    array = get_np(sm_name)
    print(np.sum(array))
    release_shared(sm_name)
```

As explained before, the code performs the np.sum() inside get_np() correctly, but not the one in the main() function. As far as I have checked, performing a copy() on the return of the get_np() function (`return np_array.copy()`) solves the problem, but I need to avoid data copies for memory efficiency.

I am pretty lost on this one, I would highly appreciate a hint on why this is not working as expected.

Comment: Referencing the buffer when creating the array does not extent the lifetime of the shared memory object, so it gets unmapped once the function ends and it goes out of scope. You need to keep the `shm` object alive as long as the `ndarray` object lives